# Show only one of the solutions of this quadratic is valid

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the following quadratic equation
$$
\gamma^2 p + \gamma(2r + 2pq - 1) + q + 2rq + pq^2 = 0
$$
with $\gamma \geq 0$ and $p \geq 0$ and $q\geq 0$. I need to show that only the "negative" solution is valid. (By negative I mean the one with $\frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ rather than the other one)

#### Attempt

The two solutions are
$$
\gamma_{1, 2} = \frac{-2r - 2pq + 1 \pm \sqrt{(2r + 2pq - 1)^2 - 4p(q + 2rq + pq^2)}}{2p}
$$
I tried using the discriminant condition, but that leads to (after semplification)
$$
(2r - 1)^2 - 8pq \geq 0
$$
which doesn't help me a lot. We know $8 pq \geq 0$ so this means that one must have either $2r - 1 > \sqrt{8pq}$ or $2r - 1 < -\sqrt{8pq}$. I am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you try to show that only the mentioned solution gives  $\gamma \geq 0$?

Comment: @insipidintegrator yes I think that's the right way to go about it, I haven't reached anything yet, but I will keep working

Comment: Look, if you can show that -2r-2pq+1 is positive, then you are done. That’s because the sqrt of the discriminant (which is a positive quantity getting subtracted from -2r-2pq+1 ) is itself less in magnitude than -2r-2pq+1 , so a-b, where a >0 and b<a, is always positive.

Comment: @insipidintegrator ooh smart. How do you know that the sqrt of the discriminant is less in magnitude than $-2r-2pq + 1$?

Comment: There is a quantity that gets subtracted from the square of -2r-2pq+1. Oopsie, I just assumed that $4p(q+2rq+pq^2)$ is positive. Just hope that it _is_ positive, so you have $\sqrt{a^2-c}\gt a$, when a, c are both positive (otherwise you’d have to involve some absolute values ). Just show somehow that $4p(q+2rq+pq^2)$ is positive, and it’s done.

Comment: @Physics_Student "*show that only the "negative" solution is valid*" $\;-\;$ That's not possible. When the two roots are real, they have the same sign since their product is positive. It is not possible that only one real root is positive.